# Can only add a certain amount of characters to string - C++

Tags: c++, string, character

I'm creating a socket application in c++ where I have to decode base64 strings. I'm using René Nyffenegger's (https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/Base64/Encoding-and-decoding-base-64-with-cpp) code to do this. The `ret` string from the `base64_decode` function I've found is always only 4 characters long, and after I spent some time debugging I've realized it all boil down to this:

```
unsigned char1 = 255;
unsigned char2 = 216;
unsigned char3 = 255;
unsigned char4 = 224;
unsigned char5 = 0;
unsigned char6 = 16;
unsigned char7 = 74;
unsigned char8 = 70;
unsigned char9 = 73;
string str;
str += char1;
str += char2;
str += char3;
str += char4;
str += char5;
str += char6;
str += char7;
str += char8;
str += char9;
```

For some reason this code only adds `char1`, `char2`, `char3` and `char4` to `str`, and the rest of the characters are ignored completely. Why is that and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: How do you know they " are ignored completely". Post an actual compilable program that illustrates your problem.

Comment: If I print str using cout after each statement or use the debugger I see that only the first 4 characters are added to the string.

Comment: Do not describe your code - post it.

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.org/2RXPG5pc) even if it's filled with a bunch of UTF-8 junk characters. Your debugger might be confused by the zero byte in the stream which represents, normally, a C "end of string" delimiter. If you're converting to `c_str()` then this byte will be a huge problem. C strings are a whole different deal and cannot contain zero bytes.

Comment: I guess it must be my debugger's fault somehow. Still not sure what to do about it though since I really need to use my debugger to do this. Thanks for taking your time

Comment: @JoeJacksson *and the rest of the characters are ignored completely.* -- No they are not ignored. To convince yourself, print out `str.size()`.  You're using functions and/or tools that recognize the null terminator and stops processing the string at the null byte.  For debuggers, see if your debugger has some sort of "memory watch", where you specify the memory to view.

Comment: It is a bad design decision of author to use `std::string` for encoded data. `std::vector<char>` should be used instead.

Comment: *I'm creating a socket application in c++* -- Which underscores the point of staying clear away from any string functions that are affected by the null terminator.  Even constructing a `std::string` from the data needs to be done carefully, i.e. `char *data; int size; ... std::string s(data, size);` would be used instead of simply `std::string s = data;`

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be the 0 in char5? C strings are null terminated, so if your string is ever cast to a C string I presume it would be truncated at that point.

Note again that this is a C issue, not a C++ issue, but there could be a point in your case where this conversion is happening.

Comment: Guessing what the problem is rarely works. If the OP cannot be bothered to produce some code that illustrates the problem you are really better off ignoring them.

Comment: @Joe You did not post code that we can compile, and did not say how you are diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Would really int main(){} have helped you understand the problem I'm having? I didn't say how I diagnosed the problem because that's obvious.